# ReactJS .js extention change as .jsx Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am beginner of react application.i am making the components earlier js extension.some one told that changes as .jsx extension. login.js to login.jsx when i call the routes after change the extension .jsx error displayed y.

Error

```
Attempted import error: './components/Index' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Index').
ERROR in ./src/App.js 15:40-45
export 'default' (imported as 'Index') was not found in './components/Index' (module has no exports)

ERROR in ./src/App.js 26:40-55
export 'default' (imported as 'UserRegistation') was not found in './components/UserRegistation' (module has no exports)

ERROR in ./src/App.js 37:40-45
export 'default' (imported as 'Login') was not found in './components/Login' (module has no exports)
```

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter,Routes,Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Index from "./components/Index";
import UserRegistation from "./components/UserRegistation";
import Login from "./components/Login";

function App() {
  return (
   <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element= { <Index/>} />
              <Route path="/register" element= { <UserRegistation/>} />
              <Route path="/login" element= { <Login/>} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Login.jsx**

```
<h1>Login</h1>
```

**file structure**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export that component as default.

Attempted import error: './components/Index' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Index').

Login.jsx

```
function Login(){
return <h1>Login<h1>
}

export default Login;
```

you can use the arrow function also

```
const Login = () => {
return <h1>Login<h1>
}

export default Login;
```

same for index.jsx

```
const Index = () => {
return (
     ...required code
    )
}

export default Index;
```

Comment: thanks sir. one doubt in React we use .js or .jsx which is good?

Comment: it's complicated both are good.
My suggestion would be to go with .js
do read this discussion [link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/87#issuecomment-234627904)
if you are a beginner, do not worry about it so much